# How can I access the values inside a json response rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

So I have installed the gem Httparty on my rails app. I test if its working on my console first so this is what I'm doing:

I get the response first from the url:

```
rate = HTTParty.get("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=USD_PHP").parsed_response
```

I get this value:

```
{"query"=>{"count"=>1}, "results"=>{"USD_PHP"=>{"id"=>"USD_PHP", "val"=>54.333011, "to"=>"PHP", "fr"=>"USD"}}}
```

By this I can access each value doing this:

```
price = rate["results"]["USD_PHP"]["val"]
54.333011
```

So basically if you type in 'price' on the console you will get the value of 54.333011.

Meanwhile when I do the steps above with this one:

```
hero = HTTParty.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes").parsed_response
 [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "npc_dota_hero_antimage",
        "localized_name": "Anti-Mage",
        "primary_attr": "agi",
        "attack_type": "Melee",
        "roles": [
            "Carry",
            "Escape",
            "Nuker"
        ],
        "legs": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "npc_dota_hero_axe",
        "localized_name": "Axe",
        "primary_attr": "str",
        "attack_type": "Melee",
        "roles": [
            "Initiator",
            "Durable",
            "Disabler",
            "Jungler"
        ],
        "legs": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "npc_dota_hero_bane",
        "localized_name": "Bane",
        "primary_attr": "int",
        "attack_type": "Ranged",
        "roles": [
            "Support",
            "Disabler",
            "Nuker",
            "Durable"
        ],
```

I get these bunch of data but I can't access each of the value inside when I try my steps above

```
id = hero["id"]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>           2: from (irb):37
>           1: from (irb):37:in '[]' TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)

I get this error.

Comment: The `hero` variable is an array.

Comment: It was always an array in the first place. You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

response is in Array of (JSON)hashes

so, you can try this

```
id = hero[0]["id"]
```

Comment: This actually works, I forgot what arrays are. Silly me!